# how to display alert/echo messages in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi i have a simple form and implemented an ajax script. My question is how to display the echo messages form the other php file which is user-file-upload.php?

I would also like to ask if i am doing ajax the right way. I am a total noob right now in ajax. Hope you could help me in the right direction. Thanks

Here is my form

```
 echo "<form action='portal-files/user-file-upload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='test_ajax'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='MAX_FILE_SIZE' value='100000' />";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='admin_id' value='$user->id' />";
    echo "<select name='id' id='form-option' class='test-only'>";
    echo '<option selected="selected">' .'Choose a User'. '</option>';

    foreach ($registeredUsers as $key => $value) {
      $registered = JFactory::getUser($value);
      echo '<option value="'.$registered->id.'">'.$registered->name.'</option>';

    }
    echo "</select>";
    echo "<input name='uploadedfile' type='file' id='custom-file-input' class='test-only' /> <br/>";
    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" id="custom-submit-input" disabled="disabled" >';
    echo '<span id="display_file"></span>';
    echo '<span id="display_user" style="visibility:hidden"></span>';
    echo "</form>";
```

Here is the user-file-upload.php

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/t4t5/sweetalert/master/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/t4t5/sweetalert/master/dist/sweetalert.css">

<?php


define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).DS.'..' ));


require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );



$target_dir = "../portal-files/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);



// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "doc" && $imageFileType != "docx" && $imageFileType != "xlsx") {
    echo "Sorry, only DOC, DOCX, XLXS.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";

        if(isset($_POST['id']))
        {

            $selectedValue = $_POST['id'];
            $adminabc = $_POST['admin_id'];

            $imageFileName = basename( $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]);



            $db = JFactory::getDbo();
            $query = $db->getQuery(true);

            $query = "INSERT INTO joom_fss_user_files (user_id,admin_id) VALUES ($selectedValue,$adminabc)";

            $db->setQuery($query);
            $result = $db->execute();



            $db = JFactory::getDbo();
            $query_user = $db->getQuery(true);

            $query_user = "INSERT INTO joom_fss_files (user_id,admin_id,file_type,file_name,path_url) VALUES ($selectedValue,$adminabc,'$imageFileType','$imageFileName', '$target_file')";

            $db->setQuery($query_user);
            $result = $db->execute();

            sweetAlert("You have successfuly uploaded a file."); 

        }


    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}


?>
```

Here is my jquery script

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>

<script>

  jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

            jQuery('#test_ajax').ajaxForm(function() { 
                e.preventDefault();

            }); 
  });

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this way, **response** is everything that you echo in .php page.

```js
$("#test_ajax").ajaxForm({
    success: function(response, textStatus, xhr, form) {
        alert(response); //alert
        $('#some-container').html(response); //show in html element
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("in ajaxForm error");
    },
    complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
        console.log("in ajaxForm complete");
    }
});
```